# Sequence tending to infinity (checking epsilon proof)

Tags: convergence-divergence, proof-writing, infinity, epsilon-delta

Question: Prove that the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ defined by $x_n=\sqrt[3]{n}+1$ tends to infinity.

Definition: $\forall K \in \mathbb{R} \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \forall n \in \mathbb{N} ,n>N:x_n>K $

Proof: Given any $K$ in real numbers, choose $N=(K-1)^3$. Given any $n$ in natural numbers with $n>N=\lceil(K-1)^3\rceil$ we have $x_n=\sqrt[3]{n}+1\geq \sqrt[3]{N}+1\ge K$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You're looking for \mathbb{N} and \mathbb{R}

Comment: Thank you I have edited the question.

Comment: Just a small nitpick: your chosen $N$ might not be a natural number.

Comment: ah that is correct, what about putting the ceiling function over it?

Comment: The number $N$ can even be negative in this way. I would slightly rephrase the definition: for all $K>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $x_n\geq K$.

Comment: @ViB taking the ceiling function will work!

Comment: @RMWGNE96 the definition in my lecture notes says $K \in \mathbb{R}$ will greater than zero also work? Also taking the ceiling function, will that mean the proof is correct?

Comment: @ViB in this case, $x_n>0$ for all $n$ so if you can prove the statement for all $K>0$ then you also have proven it for $K\leq 0$. And yes, taking the ceiling function will complete the proof.